# What number should replace the question mark in the grid?

Tags: pattern

What number should replace the question mark?

| 3 | 7 | 9 | 8 |

| 2 | 4 | 1 | 4 |

| 7 | 2 | 8 | ? |

| 9 | 6 | 2 | 6 |

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is

> **8**

Because

> For each column, by multiplying the first row digit by the last row digit, we get the middle two rows as a 2 digit number
>  Col 1
>  3 x 9 = 27
>  Col 2
>  7 x 6 = 42
>  Col 3
>  9 x 2 = 18
>  Col 4
>  8 x 6 = 4**8**